# Debug 2 projects in monodevelop

Tags: debugging, mono, project, monodevelop

i have a simple question and maybe the solution is in front of my eyes but i cant see it:
How do i debug more than one project (eg.: server and client project) in monodevelop?
It now debugs just one project (breakpoints,..). after i close the first project monodevelop says: "Connot execute "path to .exe". A debugger session is already started."

So is it possible to have more than one debugger session?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only run or debug a single application at a time (which is no different in Visual Studio, btw.), but you can run more than one instance of MonoDevelop.

If you only want to run the second application without debugging it, then you don't need to start another instance of MonoDevelop.  You can either run the other project on the command line or simply define a custom command for it.

To add a custom command, right-click the project that you want to debug in MonoDevelop, select "Options", then goto "Run" / "Custom Commands", add a "Before Execute" command there.  Click on the drop-down box on the right to see some variables that you can use for the command, such as `${SolutionDir}`.

Comment: oh, thanks =) but, is there a way to run the second application without debuging?

Comment: Oh, sure.  I thought you wanted to debug both.  I updated my answer.

Comment: In case you want to debug same project in multiple instances of MonoDevelop but with different command-line arguments - do as following: 1) Load all projects. 2) Change arguments (Project Options -> Run -> General -> Parameters) in 1st instance. 3) Start debugging. 4) Repeat steps 2 and 3 for all other instances. It is important to start debugging the project before changing arguments for the next instance, otherwise changed arguments will be synched.

Comment: This isn't true - you can set more than one startup project in VS and debug more than one project using this - in fact MD has the same option but it doesn't seem to work.